# Does ibm-cloud-private support syndicate of catelog?

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I see support statement for IBM Cloud Dedicated (Syndicated catalog) here -> https://console.bluemix.net/docs/dedicated/index.html#catalogdedicated.

Is it supported in ibm-cloud-private ?

Answer (score 1):

No, IBM Cloud Private does not use the syndicated catalog from IBM Cloud Public and Dedicated because ICP uses a helm chart catalog, while IBM Cloud Public and Dedicated use the syndicated catalog serving up service broker access to services as well as container based services. ICP doesn't have to syndicate across public datacenters like IBM Cloud Public and Dedicated because ICP is running in the datacenter of your choice and might be air-gapped (no connection to internet).  The syndicated catalog is built on the assumption of public datacenters.